# How can I check if a value exists in multiple arrays where keys are the same

Tags: php, arrays

I got an array that looks like this:

```
[0] => Array (
    [status] => success
    [field] => voornaam
    )
[1] => Array (
    [status] => success
    [field] => achternaam
    )
[2] => Array (
    [status] => success
    [field] => telefoon
    )
[3] => Array (
    [status] => error
    [field] => email
    [message] => Vul een email in
    )
[4] => Array (
    [status] => success
    [field] => huisnummer
    )
[5] => Array (
    [status] => success
    [field] => postcode
    )
[6] => Array (
    [status] => success
    [field] => straat
    )
[7] => Array (
    [status] => success
    [field] => woonplaats
    )
```

I want to check if `error` is present in any of those arrays. How can I do that?

This is how the array is built:

```
if (empty($accountform['voornaam'])) {
    $return[] = array('status' => 'error', 'field' => 'voornaam', 'message' => 'Vul een voornaam in');
} else {
    $return[] = array('status' => 'success', 'field' => 'voornaam');
}

if (empty($accountform['achternaam'])) {
    $return[] = array('status' => 'error', 'field' => 'achternaam', 'message' => 'Vul een achternaam in');
} else {
    $return[] = array('status' => 'success', 'field' => 'achternaam');
}

if (empty($accountform['telefoon'])) {
    $return[] = array('status' => 'error', 'field' => 'telefoon', 'message' => 'Vul een telefoonnummer in');
} else {
    $return[] = array('status' => 'success', 'field' => 'telefoon');
}

if (empty($accountform['email'])) {
    $return[] = array('status' => 'error', 'field' => 'email', 'message' => 'Vul een email in');
}else if(!filter_var($accountform['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $return[] = array('status' => 'error', 'field' => 'email', 'message' => 'Vul een geldig emailadres in');
} else {
    $return[] = array('status' => 'success', 'field' => 'email');
}

if (empty($accountform['huisnummer'])) {
    $return[] = array('status' => 'error', 'field' => 'huisnummer', 'message' => 'Vul een huisnummer in');
} else {
    $return[] = array('status' => 'success', 'field' => 'huisnummer');
}

if (empty($accountform['postcode'])) {
    $return[] = array('status' => 'error', 'field' => 'postcode', 'message' => 'Vul een postcode in');
} else {
    $return[] = array('status' => 'success', 'field' => 'postcode');
}

if (empty($accountform['straat'])) {
    $return[] = array('status' => 'error', 'field' => 'straat', 'message' => 'Vul een straat in');
} else {
    $return[] = array('status' => 'success', 'field' => 'straat');
}

if (empty($accountform['woonplaats'])) {
    $return[] = array('status' => 'error', 'field' => 'woonplaats', 'message' => 'Vul een woonplaats in');
} else {
    $return[] = array('status' => 'success', 'field' => 'woonplaats');
}
```

I tried:

```
if (in_array('error', $return)) {
    echo "There is an error";
}
```

But the if statement never fires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$status_rows = array_column($your_array,'status');
var_dump(in_array('error',$status_rows));
```

You can use [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to fetch all statuses and use [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check it's existence.

Answer (score 0):

you can use array_search and check if it exists or not

```
$key = array_search('error', array_column($return, 'status'));
if($key){
   echo 'found';
}else{
   echo 'not found';
}
```

Comment: Make sure you do strict comparisons if you are using array_search because a particular key can be found at 0th index as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why your code is not working is because $result has values inside another arrays like [0] and [1] and so on like this ..

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [status] => error
            [field] => telefoon
            [message] => Vul een telefoonnummer in
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [status] => success
            [field] => achternaam
        )

)
```

So if you want your code to work you'll need $result[0], $result[1] and so on.. Hence your code should be inside foreach loop

```
foreach ($return as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array('error', $value)) {
        echo "There is an error";
    }
}
```

$value now has $result datas without [0][1], now you can compare with in_array fn.